# Detect sentences that contain a valid number range

Tags: regex, numbers, range

I am trying to write a regex expression that detects sentences that have a number range, for example:
"I eat 2-6 pizzas per day"
"My weight is between 50.22-220.5 kg."

But not numbers with more hyphens:
"My phone number is 1-23-4567"
Or with :
"I use WD-40 to put my pants on."

So far I have come up with:

```
\b\d+-\d+\b
```

But it still detects things like 123-2312-12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If lookarounds are supported, you could write the pattern as:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:\.\d+)?-\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` A whitespace boundary to the left
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `-` Match literally
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?!\S)` A whitespace boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mZG8j/1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your question is way too broad and cannot necessarily be handled by a static regex, but I'll try to give you an essence of how to go about implementing ranges using regex. So, the following pattern for example:

```
[2-6][1-8]
```

matches any number between `21` and `68`.

You could use something like this, and try to implement what you want, but as I said, it would be difficult all kinds of ranges with a static regex. You can try and play with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/qJ7Xfa/1).

Answer (score 0):

This solution excludes all not allowed sequences:

`(?!(()|()))` excludes patterns with an OR `|` condition

`(\d+-\d+-)` excludes sentences which contain digits in the form of **1-23-**

`([A-Z]-\d+)` ecludes all big letters followed by a hyphen and a digit. like **D-4**.

```
^((?!(\d+-+\d+-)|[A-Z]-\d+).)+$
```